# Why does my space station keep converting to a ship and drift away?

Tags: space-engineers

I am playing the "Star System" scenario offline in Survival mode with meteor showers enabled.

I started out on the earth-like planet, but I have just left it and built a space station in orbit above it on an altitude of about 55 km (measured from the GPS waypoint I put at my old station on the ground). It is already of a quite decent size with a pressurized command center, artificial gravity, docking ring, assemblers, refineries and gatling gun turrets.

However, it has happened twice to me now that the space station suddenly started to drift and rotate. I noticed in the "Info" tab of its terminal that it was suddenly converted to a ship. Both times I managed to stabilized it using a docked ship and turn it back into a station by clicking "convert to station" in the terminal.

What could be the reason for the station turning into a ship and what can I do to prevent it from happening again?

Some things which I suspect to have something to do with it but could also be coincidences:

- The first time I was just making some architectural changes to the station where I was deconstructing and replacing a lot of blocks.
- The second time it appeared as if the station just suffered some minor damage from a meteor shower. I wasn't present at that time but nearby (mining an asteroid about 5km away).

Comment: Do you have *Station Voxel Support* enabled?  If so you'll need to either anchor your station to an asteroid or place "station keeping" engines and gyros.

Comment: Could it be that the very first stationblock you placed got destroyed when you where deconstructing or when the station got hit by the meteors?

Comment: @tjd I'm sorry, but I can not find a setting by that name in the "Advanced World Setting", neither when I change the settings of my savegame nor when I create a new game. Maybe it got removed or renamed in a recent update? There is a setting "Unsupported Stations" though which I have indeed disabled.

Comment: @BadAtPHP That is indeed a plausible hypothesis. I think I indeed removed the first block I placed during my remodeling. But I did not re-add that block before the second event. I wonder how the game decided which block became the new "master block" of the "new" station. If I knew which one it is, I could test that hypothesis by removing it too... and if it turns out to be true I could then build 3 layers of heavy armor around it.

Comment: Well there is your issue. Turn on "Unsupported Stations" and convert your stationgrid to a station. Or just place thrusters at every side of the station if you want to do overcome it in a "more legit" manner. Oh, 1 more thing to be 100% sure: did you convert the stationgrid to a station from a connected ship, or did you do it directly in one of the station's control terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was most likely a bug, from the newest patch notes:

> fixed a bug when removing a block from a station caused it to convert to ship [[source]](https://forum.keenswh.com/threads/update-1-185-5-beta-improvements.7399033/)

So I guess it should be fixed now.